# Check a count Function in Where

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, where-clause

i have a question about the count function in PostgreSQL
so if i have this query

```
SELECT dept_id, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM employees
WHERE salary > 50000
GROUP BY dept_id;
```

and i want to check if the Total > 2. i tried to write:

```
Where Total > 2
```

or

```
Where Count (*) > 2
```

but it's wrong, could anyone help me with it? Thanks

Comment: you must use having clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause was added to `SQL` because the `WHERE` keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.
So, then you should use `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT dept_id, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM employees
WHERE salary > 50000
GROUP BY dept_id
HAVING count(*) > 2;
```

Comment: You should mention when to use `HAVING` over `WHERE`

Comment: @Harlekuin It's true, it was a poor answer. I haved added when to use HAVING. Ty for the tip.

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful,